# Need to add unique object in the list in AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, recursion

I have the following array in my angularjs application.

```
$scope.inputList = [
  {  'id' :0 
    "typeName": "Large Text Box"    
  }      
];
```

I have dropdown with `$scope.inputList`, now when I select "Large Text Box" and click add button, it should add new object with unique 'typeName', containing "Large Text Box". So I wrote the following.

Initially `selName` will be `"Large Text Box"`

```
$scope.addNewField = function(selName) {
     var     fieldName  =  `"Large Text Box"`;    
            var existingFieldList = _.filter($scope.inputFieldList, {
                typeName: selName;
            });
            if (existingFieldList.length > 0) {
                fieldName = fieldName + existingFieldList.length;
                $scope.newObj.typeNme =    fieldName;
                $scope.newObj.id=    existingFieldList.length;
                $scope.inputFieldList.push($scope.newObj);   
                } 
}
```

This logic is adding every time unique `typeName` containing `"Large Text Box"`. And now I have the inputList as

```
 $scope.inputList = [
      {  'id' :0 
        "typeName": "Large Text Box"    
      },
     {  'id' :1 
        "typeName": "Large Text Box1"    
      }

    ];
```

Like this I have added 10 times and but now I need to support delete also. But as I am deleting any one object and adding new object to the list, the logic is going wrong as that particular name is already present. Is there any simple solution to this.

The `id` and `typeName` no need to be in sync. I mean, if `id` is `2`, `typeName` need not be only `"Large Text Box2"` but the newly added `typeName` should contain `"Large Text Box"`